# Pivot table with multiple columns SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I have a table with agent availability and I am trying to use pivot tables to put it into readable format for users.

[image]

How can I achieve something like this?

[image]

This is my query so far

```
select *
FROM 
(select SP.salespersonid, SP.Firstname + ' ' + SP.GivenName as Agent,  A.Fordate,  A.ForSlot,  A.Available

from t_salespersons SP
INNER JOIN t_availability A ON SP.SalesPersonID = A.SalesPersonID
INNER JOIN t_salesmanagers SM ON SP.AreaID = SM.SalesManagerID
WHERE  A.Fordate >='01-oct-20' and  SM.SalesManagerID = '2')
as availability_table


PIVOT
(Max(Fordate)
For
Agent in ([Agent Name], [Available Date], [Slot], [Avail])
) as PIVOT_TABLE
```

Comment: and what happens when you run that query, and why is that wrong?

Comment: I get the Date in 1 column and then get NULL in the other columns.

Comment: The values in the `IN` (in the `PIVOT`) are the values you want to pivot on, which will become the name of the new column. Your image shows that you want dates as the names of the columns. Personally, however, I suggest using conditional aggregation (aka a Cross Tab) over the restrictive `PIVOT` operator.